# JUnit - compare unknown Collection and ArrayList

Tags: java, list, junit, collections, hamcrest

I want to compare `Collection` (products) (in my case it is `LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues`) and `ArrayList`.

The test

```
assertThat(products, equalTo(Lists.newArrayList(product1, product2, product3)));
```

doesn't work because LinkedValues doesn't implement `equals` method.
So I changed my test to:

```
  assertThat(new ArrayList<>(products), equalTo(Lists.newArrayList(product1, product2, product3)));
```

Is there a better solution where I do not have to check if the collection implements `equals` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Hamcrest, you should use the slightly confusingly named method [`Matchers.contains()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)). It checks whether the target collection contains the same elements in the same order as the original collection.

Given

```
Map<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
linkedHashMap.put("a", "A");
linkedHashMap.put("b", "B");
```

This will pass:

```
assertThat(linkedHashMap.values(), contains("A", "B"));
```

and this would fail:

```
assertThat(linkedHashMap.values(), contains("B", "A"));
```

---

Note that Hamcrest has been long dead and even though it works fine and is okay for 99% of usages, you will be shocked by how good [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) is, how much functionality it provides and how easy asserting can be.

With AssertJ:

```
assertThat(linkedHashMap.values()).containsExactly("A", "B");
```

Comment: Heh I checked `contains` before but as you said I understood wrong what it does. And thank you for recommending AssertJ. I checked it and it is great :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data type you're using already has an equals method, then there's no need to check for an (un-)implemented `equals()` function. Otherwise, you would have to create something that compares the data you're using.

On a side note, the two lines of code you have are identical. Did you mean to put something else in the second line?

Comment: The lines shouldn't be identical. Sorry for my mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: Awesome; so, like Mike just said, you could use a boolean expression, such as Arrays.equal and ensure that it should always evaluate to "true."

Otherwise, for a custom object inside something like an ArrayList, you would need to define your own equals method, be it for the ArrayList (which i believe Java's API should have something for this) or for the object itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Arrays.equals`:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(products.toArray(), new Product[] {product1, product2, product3}));
```

This checks array sizes and odering of items. Your product class should implement `equals()` to be something meaningful.

Note that you can use `ArrayList.toArray()` to get an array if needed.

Comment: @AppiDevo minor typo, should be `equals` but otherwise it works.

Comment: It doesn't because products is `Collection`

Comment: Apologies, I missed that in your post. You should be able to call `products.toArray()` first, then use that array for the comparison.